# What would be a beautiful house plant suited to the Atlantic winter?

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations

I'm looking for a Christmas gift for my girlfriend, and I thought of a nice plant she could keep in her room. We live in Baltimore. I'm looking for something that would be beautiful, but not take a whole lot of effort, and would be able to live in the Atlantic winter, with not too much light and warmth.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you would need to provide more detail such as which direction the window faces, distance the plant will be from the window, level of experience your girlfriend has with plants..

Comment: Which Baltimore? There are at least two on the Atlantic: Maryland in the USA, and the original in Co. Cork in Ireland. Also, are you looking for a plant she can keep for several years, or one for a single season?

Comment: Baltimore, MD. A single season would be fine, or a longer-lasting one. It's for a bedroom, so I think it shouldn't be too large.

Comment: Is there enough floor space to take a taller, narrow plant? Or does it have to stand on something? And the direction of the window is all important, as Kevinsky has asked about.